# What does a "cannot open include file" error mean in Visual C++ 2010?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, header-files, bgi

Could you please help me in solving the below error:

> fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'graphics.h': No such file or directory

```
#include<dos.h>
#include<graphics.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
union REGS in,o;

circ()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<15;i++)
        circle(320,240,i*10);
    rectangle(240,160,400,320);
}

bulb()
{
    int i=1,c=1;
    randomize();
    while(!kbhit())
    {
        if((i%2)==0)
            setcolor(c++);
        setfillstyle(1,getcolor());
        circle(320,240,i*20);
        putpixel(320-i+2,240-i+2,1);
        floodfill(320-i+2,240-i+2,getcolor());
        delay(1000);
        i++;
        if(i>=5)
            i=1;
    }
}

dot()
{
    int i,j,of=40,wid=5;
    setcolor(8);
    setfillstyle(1,getcolor());
    for(i=of;i<getmaxx();i+=of)
        bar(i,0,i+wid,getmaxy());

    for(i=of;i<getmaxy();i+=of)
        bar(0,i,getmaxx(),i+wid);

    for(i=of;i<getmaxx();i+=of)
        for(j=of;j<getmaxy();j+=of)
        {
            setcolor(15);
            setfillstyle(1,getcolor());
            circle(i+2,j+2,4);
            floodfill(i+2,j+2,getcolor());
        }

}

void main()
{
    int x=0,y=10,gd=DETECT,gm,i;
    initgraph(&gd,&gm,"c:\tc\bgi");
    setcolor(YELLOW);
    settextstyle(1,0,6);
    outtextxy(0,240,"Count the black dots.....");
    sleep(4);
    cleardevice();
    dot();
    getch();
    cleardevice();
    setcolor(YELLOW);
    settextstyle(1,0,4);
    outtextxy(0,240,"I bet the lines of rectangle are straight.....");
    sleep(4);
    getch();
    cleardevice();
    circ();
    getch();
    closegraph();
}
```

Comment: There are error messages that are obscure/incomprehensible or give no indication of what's the matter. This one does neither; it's as clear as it gets. Can you read, think and operate a computer?

Comment: how to add graphics.h file...

Comment: Firstly, do you have a file called graphics.h? You're obviously #include-ing it for some functions - where do those functions come from? There is no standard windows header called graphics.h. Are you actually using those functions - if you delete the #include line does your program compile?

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to compile code that includes the header file `graphics.h`, but your compiler cannot find that file. There are a couple of possible reasons why not:

1. The `include` directive that you've written at the top of your code file may be incorrect. There are two syntactical forms, and you need to make sure that you've used the right one in order for the pre-processor to search in the correct location. For a complete run-down, check the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36k2cdd4.aspx).
2. You may not have the Windows SDK installed, which includes the header files you need to call functions from the Win32 API. You can download the latest version of the SDK [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb980924).
3. I have no idea where you got this code, but the only `graphics.h` that I know about is an *extremely* old graphics library for Borland Turbo C/C++ compilers. It works with 16-bit MS-DOS applications, not modern day Windows programs. This is *not* a standard Windows header. You need to be using `windows.h` instead for all of your graphics functions.

**EDIT:** I see you've posted your code. Unfortunately, you're not going to have much luck with including `dos.h`, either. Refer specifically to my third suggestion above. I don't know where you got this code, but you're not going to be able to compile it on Visual C++. The "Visual" part means you're creating a Windows application. The code you're using is including proprietary header files included with versions of Borland's Turbo C/C++ compilers that ran under MS-DOS (the text-based predecessor to Windows). You need to find some updated code or use a (much) older compiler.

If you absolutely *need* to compile that code, it looks like you can download an ancient copy of Borland Turbo C++ 3.0 [here](http://www.top4download.com/turbo-c-/aklqwuba.html). I assume that it's abandonware at this point, but you're on your own. I wasn't even programming that long ago.

Comment: codes has been added above..pls have a look at it...and let me know where am i going wrong...

Comment: @abhi: I added more to my answer, in light of the code you posted.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Thank you so much for your comments...can u please help me with a source code of a simple game which use windoows api...please

Comment: You could try the XNA tools and samples: http://create.msdn.com/en-us/education/roadmap

Comment: @Rup: Umm, those samples don't create applications targeting the Windows API. They're for the Windows Phone, which is a little bit different beast.

Comment: @abhi: You're going to have to re-write your code. That's more than I can help with here. I strongly suggest picking up a book on programming Windows C++ apps using Visual Studio. Specifically, I'd recommend the classic [Programming Windows](http://www.amazon.com/dp/157231995X/?tag=stackoverfl08-20) by [Charles Petzold](http://www.charlespetzold.com/). But if you're the skeptical type, peruse these related questions here on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599500/which-is-the-best-book-to-learn-visual-c, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194519/good-book-for-learning-native-visual-c

Comment: As far as I know, most non-Mac computers nowadays can boot into MS-DOS, although I/O may be a real problem.  There are MS-DOS emulators out there, and in conjunction with an ancient copy of Turbo C++ you may be able to compile and run.

Comment: OK, fair enough. Yes, they're actually for XNA which is a simplified .NET version of DirectX etc. which targets all of PC, XBox and Windows Phone. Which is going to be a much simpler environment to develop a game if that's what he wants to do. Mind you so would Flash or something like that.

Comment: @Rup: I don't think I understand your point. Yes, learning a different language altogether might be easier. But XNA, although I'm completely unfamiliar it, is based on .NET, which is *managed* code. It doesn't use the Windows API. And it looks to me like most of the samples are in C#, rather than C++ (they're *entirely* different languages). The question was about C++, and the asker's comment asked specifically for help designing a simple game using the Windows API.

Comment: @Cody OK, sure - I read it as 'help me write a simple game on Windows' - for which the Windows API isn't a great starting point. And the OP clearly isn't comfortable in C++ so I didn't think that mattered. Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 1):

Both `graphics.h` and `conio.h` are only available on Borland compilers (they are vendor specific extensions).

(Note: I believe `conio.h` actually exists on recent msvc++ compilers, but it's not 100% compatible with Borland's version)

If you're using MSVC, you're going to have to implement your logic using the [Windows API's Console Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682073.aspx) instead.